# What does the Qt configure option "-commercial" actually do

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, configure

The help for configure in Qt commercial source 4.8.7 lists an option "-commercial" with the following description.

> -commercial ........ Compile and link the Commercial Edition of Qt.

The options are also listed here, with the same brief explanation of this parameter, http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/configure-options.html

Since there are separate source packages for commercial (or enterprise) and open source, why is a flag needed? Also I can confirm that it successfully compiles also without giving this flag, which makes me wonder even more...

What does it actually do?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but could have to do with the embedded licence texts...

Comment: Like king_nak, I don't know exactly. The differenc between commerial and public licenses is, that you are not allowed to publish opensource-qtlibs for money. (Commercial you are). - To see if a qt lib is commercial, there must be some information linked in. I guess the '-commercial' flag will do this: Link commercial information into qt libraries.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess that might be it. Seems that it could be predefined (or at least default) when building the commercial/enterprise sources, but I guess this reduces the number of differences between the two packages...

Answer (score 0):

If you configure without commercial or opensource option you get asked with which license you want to use Qt: the commercial or the opensource one. I assume using one of these options just pre-answers this question.

EDIT: Sorry, I mixed something up. Forget the "answer".

Comment: When do I get asked about this exactly? Have built qt without this flag up until now and have never been asked this question.